# replacing word after multiple spaces

Tags: regex, replace, sed

I need to replace a word after multiple spaces :

actually the file contains this string :

```
local   all             all                                     peer
```

Which I have to change with

```
local   all             all                                     md5
```

I tried various combinations , including

```
sed -i.bak 's/all[\+ ]peer/md5/g'  file
```

with no luck .

Any idea ?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this (using `GNU sed-Version 4.2.1`):

```
sed -E -i.bak 's/(all\s+)peer/\1md5/' file
```

Comment: +1 I would generalize `all +` to `all[[:space:]]+` to pick up tabs as well as spaces

Comment: @David Then it would be nice to mark an answer as the correct one. :)

Comment: @speakr : thanks ... I didn't know I had to do it ... I  Thought It was automatic for the answer with more votes lol

Answer (score 2):

#### GNU sed

```
sed -r -i.bak '/^local\s+(all\s+){2}peer$/s/\S+$/md5/' file
```

Comment: This will also remove the preceding `all  ...` substring.

Comment: @David    hmmm, I tested it now again and it works with `GNU sed-Version 4.2.1`. can make a screen shot.

Comment: @David btw. I read in an other comment, you needed the replacement only in one line? This is not in your question :confused:

Comment: Endoro , yes , but that is not the point ... I can change all the lines with that content ( there is only one ) , the point is that I need to substitute the word peer only when follow " local all all " , and leaving everything else as it is :)

Comment: **only** when follow: yes, you are right, my code does remove peer (every word at the end) always, sorry. But I will look into it :)

Comment: @David added the full address of the line, sorry for the delay :)

Answer (score 2):

Am I missing some part of this problem?  I made a file with the first line above as contents, then ran the simplest possible sed command on it ... and came out with the 2nd line.

```
~ >cat test.txt
local   all             all                                     peer

~ >sed 's/peer/md5/g' test.txt
local   all             all                                     md5
```

works fine with multiple lines as well ...

```
~ >cat test.txt
local   all             all                                     peer
local   all             all                                     peer
local   all             all                                     peer
local   all             all                                     peer
local   all             all                                     peer
local   all             all                                     peer
~ >sed 's/peer/md5/g' test.txt
local   all             all                                     md5
local   all             all                                     md5
local   all             all                                     md5
local   all             all                                     md5
local   all             all                                     md5
local   all             all                                     md5
```

The only time this will not work is if the word "peer" shows up somewhere else on a line where you do not want it replaced with md5 ...

This one replaces only the first occurance of the search term:

```
~ >cat test.txt
local   all             all                                     peer
local   all             all                                     peer
local   all             all                                     peer
local   all             all                                     peer
local   all             all                                     peer
local   all             all                                     peer
~ >sed '0,/peer/s//md5/' test.txt
local   all             all                                     md5
local   all             all                                     peer
local   all             all                                     peer
local   all             all                                     peer
local   all             all                                     peer
local   all             all                                     peer
```

Comment: Perhaps `s/\bpeer\b/md5/` or `s/\<peer\>/md5/`  to be on the safe side.

Comment: Hi Ron , Yes there are multiple lines with " local all all " and multiple lines which end in "peer" :)

Comment: Hey Ron ... this change the word peer in every line ! That's not what I was looking for .

Comment: Hey David, it would be a good idea to put all the criteria in the question. :-)

Comment: Sorry @RonSavage :) You'r right ... I tend to summarize too much .

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/\(all *all  *\).*/\1md5/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
sed -i.bak -e "s/\(all[ ]\+\)peer/\1md5/g" file
```

You need to escape `()+` characters.
Space could be like: `[ ]` with `\+` you say that it should be more than 0. Replace it with `*` if in some cases you do not have a space between "all" and "peer"

In the replace part you should use `\1` - back-reference to the first found part: `all`, and only `peer` will be replaced with `md5`

Comment: thanks Kostanos, but I got this error : sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `-'

Comment: Sorry, the order of -i and -e parameters was incorrect. Already edited the answer, try it again.

Comment: Works fine this one too ! :) Thx

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -pe 's/(all[\s]+)peer/$1md5/g' your_file
```