# The 5th word from sentence using RegEx

Tags: regex

I have a problem. I want to get the word `trust` from this sentence and replace it with `md5` using RegEx:

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
```

Comment: What language are you willing to use?

Comment: I beg your pardon, buth `trust` is the fifth WORD, not letter.

Comment: This question looks very similar to [that one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17014904/).

Comment: Does `trust` always appears at end ?

Comment: May be. I don't know what will be the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find : `^((?:\S+\s+){4})\S+` 
replace by : `${1}md5`

For example, in Perl, i'd do:

```
my $str = 'host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust';
$str =~ s/^((?:\S+\s+){4})\S+/${1}md5/;
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex captures the fifth word: `^.+\s+.+\s+.+\s+.+\s+([^\s]+)\*\*` and requires that two asterisks came after the word (and the asterisks are not captured)

Answer (score 0):

You can also have a look at this regex:

```
^(?:.+?\s+){4}(\b.+?\b)
```

Replace using this regex to `md5` will do the job

Comment: Have you checked this one ?